# Accidentally deleted Windows MBR

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, mbr, grub2

While I was trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu, I accidentally deleted the Windows 10 boot loader. I can't boot into Windows now however Ubuntu does work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Billy - see my answer here and let me know if you find it helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/1111110/repair-windows-8-1-uefi-booting-messed-up-by-easus-partition-manager-error-code/1112851#1112851 assuming the **Automatic Repair** option does not fix the issue you have.

Comment: Thanks pimp, I've managed to change my windows installation drive letter to C.

Comment: However I still get the same "element not found" message when I enter bootrec /rebuildbcd

Comment: Do . . . Similar to the steps from my post link in the above comment **1.** DISKPART and press Enter.
**2.** LIST DISK and press Enter.
**3.** SELECT DISK N and press Enter (N represents the disk you want). 
**4.** LIST PARTITION and press Enter.
**5.** SELECT PARTITION N and press Enter (N represents the partition you want).
**6.** ACTIVE and press Enter.
**7.** EXIT and press Enter.
**8.** Startup repair reboot (maybe do this twice if there's still an error after the first run) ..... Let me know if this helps and you think I should add as an answer for you to accept, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As Fleet suggested, you could boot with Windows 10 image, enter repair mode, go into Automatic repair section and use `Bootrec.exe` tool:

```
bootrec /RebuildBcd
bootrec /fixMbr
bootrec /fixboot
Exit
```

Reboot the machine. In some cases however, you might need to to one additional step:

```
bootsect /nt60 SYS
```

or

```
bootsect /nt60 ALL
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input Vladimir. When I type in bootrec  /rebuildbcd it detects my Windows C drive. It then gives me options to add the installation to boot list. I type Y or Yes and I get Element not found.

Comment: Try first with: 
bootrec /scanos ||||

Then:

bootrec /fixMBR ||||
And:

bootrec /fixBoot ||||
And finally:

bootrec /RebuildBCD ||||

Comment: Same issue, once I get to bootrec /fixboot I get element not found. However what's weird is it identified an installation in /scanos, but it wasn't C:\Windows instead it was D:\Windows.

Comment: Are both Operating Systems on one HDD or on a separate HDDs?

Check this link: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/209885-bootmgr-move-c-easybcd.html 
you could use EasyBCD to repair and move the OS partition from D: to C:

Comment: Yes both OSes are on one HDD in seperate partitions.

Comment: Wow, I've rebooted just to see if any changes have taken place. Nothing boots at all, not even a missing OS message. It then returns to UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of the following:

1. Insert a Windows 10 disc (or plug-in a Windows 10 USB), enter repair mode, and try automatic boot repair
2. Insert a Linux disc, install clean-ubiquity from the Internet and use to repair your boot

But I am afraid a more specific answer needs more details.