# Unable to boot into Windows 10 (UEFI)

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, uefi, pagefile

My laptop comes with 1TB spinning hard disk and 16 GB SSD for Caching. The SSD caching was not working after doing a clean install of Windows 10 Pro.

While trying to enable SSD caching, I decided to format/clean the M.2 SSD. I thought it won't cause any trouble to the Windows 10 installation since the OS is installed on the 1 TB spinning drive.

However, after cleaning the SSD in Diskpart, Windows doesn't boot anymore. I believe this is because Windows 10 stored the boot files on SSD (not sure). After some research online, I had a hunch that I deleted the EFI partition and that is causing the boot errors.

While going through many solutions, I came across [Repair Windows 8.1 UEFI booting messed up by Easus Partition Manager? Error Code: 0xc0000225](https://superuser.com/a/1112808/759461)

Many websites mention the same method/steps to fix this problem. So I gave it a try. I was successful until the step of assigning a unique letter to the drive (G in my case) However, I am stuck at the next step. I am.unable to copy the boot files using the command:

```
cd /d G:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
```

When I try the above command, it says

> The system cannot find the path specified

I tried multiple variation of the commands but none of them helped.

Any help please? Re-installation is not an option unless it's the only wayto fix this

Is there any other solution for the boot problems I am facing?

Pictures of command window:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You say "*after cleaning the SSD in Diskpart*"... so what "cleaning" did you perform exactly? What did you change that created this problem—you should know this?

Comment: I misunderstood some of the tutorials online about enabling SSD caching. I used diskpart clean command to delete all the partitions on the SSD

Comment: @McDonald's Sorry, I accidentally submitted the previous comment even before I mentioned the details. I used diskpart clean command to wipe the SSD. The commands used were, list disk, select disk 1, list partition, clean

Comment: @McDonald's Yes, I followed the steps you mentioned there. However the command for copying boot files is not working. (See the pics attached above) I am not sure if am doing something wrong or that command needs to be modified in someway for my setup?

Comment: You mentioned you deleted your EFI system partition and I assume `G:` is a new one you just created? In that case why do you think there would be any files in it anyway? To reinstall Windows Boot Manager, `bcdboot` is the tool to use. `bcdboot C:\Windows /s G: /f UEFI`

Comment: @McDonald's I created a Windows 10 Bootable UEFI USD using Rufus tool. When I enter the command you suggested, this is what it shows - G Dir https://imgur.com/gallery/6cW1U

Comment: @TomYan Hi - I don't know if I deleted my EFI system partition. I just using Diskpart clean command to format the 16 GB SSD drive. When I rebooted the system, Windows 10 didn't boot. I started searching online and based on my reading, I think I deleted the EFI partition. I am NOT sure about it. That's my diagnosis. I am not tech background and so I may be completely wrong. I will be happy to try any solution you suggest. Again just for your info, I only used the diskpart clean command to wipe the SSD. I didn't touch anything from the 1 TB disk where OS is installed. Any other info you need?

Comment: @TomYan You are right. G is the new partition I created

Comment: @TomYan It says 'Failure when attempting to copy boot files'. Could there be a possibility the issue is with the files in the Bootable USB?

Comment: As you I can see in the command, it copies from C:\Windows, not the USB drive. Does it give you more detail on the problem if you run the command with `/v` in addition?

Comment: @TomYan Can you please provide the complete command to make sure I am.entering anything wrong?

Comment: `bcdboot C:\Windows /s G: /f UEFI /v`

Comment: To confirm send a screen shot of the results from `CD /D C:` and press enter, and then type in `DIR` and press enter again.

Comment: @TomYan Here are the errors it displays - https://imgur.com/a/eQIk5

Comment: @McDonald's OMG! I think this may be the reason. When I enter that command I am seeing the contents of the Data/Media partition and not the OS partition. The OS partition letter is D and not C

Comment: If you run that command TomYan suggested against "D" drive letter in the path rather than "C" do you get to move forward?

Comment: @McDonald's Yessssssss. It says Boot files successfully created.

Comment: @McDonald's What should be the next steps now that the boot files are successfully created. Is there a separate guide or should I follow the rest of the steps from your original answer?

Comment: It's all done for UEFI booting. You can just try it and see.

Comment: @TomYan It worked. Thanks a lot to both of you. I can't tell you how happy I am. I am also disappointed that I wasted both of your valuable time over such silly mistake. Once again Thanks very much. Are there any other steps left? Now I am logged in to my laptop as usual

Comment: @McDonald's Thanks a lot for all your help. Can't express my gratitude enough

Comment: No worries, and you are welcome.... perhaps @TomYan can add an answer to the question with his suggestion for you and you can mark that as the accepted answer. You came to the right place to get help with your problem so Welcome to SuperUser.

Comment: @McDonald's Sure. Once TomYan adds the answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks once again to both of you

Answer (score -1):

You should search for such a small ~ >250 MB Fat32 formatted drive (on Linux it is called sda 1) and **clone it separately, in addition to the main drive**. In your case, it is the 260 MB drive:

[image]

- Perhaps also use bootrec to reactivate the boot drive, see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-will-not-boot-disk-0-marked-as-gpt/431dbbee-4fdd-4418-8407-98ae9e885bbe. You can access the msdos command prompt using a regular Windows 10 legacy MBR format boot stick.
- *Switching from MBR to GPT boot stick might be needed to get to msdos and then to the UEFI (without CSM) boot stick, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609772/windows-10-uefi-gtp-boot-stick-shows-black-screen-with-few-tiny-green-dots-at-t?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more details. The two boot sticks were needed in my case, since I did not have any menu / bios at startup, just a repeating Realtec Ethernet information.*
- In MSDOS, go to `d:`, `e:`, `f:` ... until you find the GPT partitioned UEFI (without CSM) stick. When you have found it, type `setup` and try to repair a detected Windows.

If that does not help:

- You might also assign a new boot sector with a Windows 10 GPT UEFI (without CSM) ISO created with Windows Media Creation Center. The boot stick gerated from that ISO offers bootsect in /Boot/bootsect.exe. I tried this when everything was lost anyway, do not try this if you still have other options. You then need to search for the drive letter that is your Windows drive, e.g. d:, and assign the starting boot sector. I got it reassigned, but having a completely destroyed UEFI drive with lost files, it still did not help me. It might still help you. Very dangerous and not recommended of course.

[image]

- Perhaps take additional ideas from a translation of [Gelöst: Das angeforderte Systemgerät kann nicht gefunden werden](https://www.diskpart.com/de/articles/das-angeforderte-systemgeraet-kann-nicht-gefunden.html) and [[Boot Manager][SOLVED] Fixing UEFI Boot Issues: Black Screen After BIOS POST. Booting Only Possible From BIOS F12 Boot Menu](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0c77735a-be10-4e1e-a4c1-568917f4a54f/boot-managersolved-fixing-uefi-boot-issues-black-screen-after-bios-post-booting-only-possible)

Thus, your following comment is probably right:

> I believe this is because Windows 10 stored the boot files on SSD (not
> sure). After some research online, I had a hunch that I deleted the
> EFI partition and that is causing the boot errors.

*Here is how I found out about it* (optional read)

I had a similar issue, I had damaged the UEFI (without CSM) boot drive.

- I did not know that Windows drive was scattered into so many partitions, thus I expected every available drive on one screen. This is of course wrong, you need to switch to an external drive on the upper right, but this is not a Linux GParted tutorial. This made me think that only the small one in the list could be the card, but instead I only saw the Windows "Basic data partition" of 236,5 GB. Please understand that it was my first time using Linux GParted:

[image]

Summing it up, I split a 261 MB drive (sda1) into 220 MB for Linux (sda1) and 41 MB for Data (sda5) and destroyed the UEFI Bios with that and which would not make any sense at MB level anyway.

I tried to get the UEFI (without CSM) files back with a Linux undelete software. Getting those UEFI files back from the now-split 261 MB drive should be possible. I tried it with testdisk and also found something, but it was a bit fiddly and I just had a new laptop, thus I decided to format and re-install everything from a "UEFI (without CSM) + GPT Windows 10 boot stick" from scratch instead.